# Azure AD not working with spring-boot webflux

Tags: azure, spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, spring-webflux

I am trying to integrate Azure's AD in my spring-boot app. I have pushed the project onto github (https://github.com/praveenk007/azure-ad).

The authorization code is generated and redirected to below redirect URI:

```
https://localhost:8081/login?code=OAQABAAIAAAAm-06blBE1TpVMil8KPQ41GNiib9Q4VuBeBjtPhyypfg50XD6swPFt4jE4G1sEaG0zuxgPdGnS43ygiZ2dZB7nxuaXSnbqMzEtdEbMiKmTlYb343BpHOD2xL0dpkkTZQk8kesIwjzzE7B3aHG7xFEhITzuBsctrbBadsUuykNdVq8CCRIYQHuxwSA2g59LDoRrJPbGncKtfDgoMNUxPk0gpJwxCf4KttbA3qe8BTXweYdYaZ5mJs2x2blY3hTVId9PDEFGS_XULvHMAMR3Q6af_B2T2TwLlOKufVYcX6R5nQTaYtpSQXqrCd2TYbBZ8Oj-B4lKpw1Ds6OC6R-wvFR6TpWRNlqzItaE0I3KlKTN5EFDso74A2Ky1B52waG5FCwWSwD4-kchKl-IEBRgPUd5UzHOlHECs_TZQpvwvMtek-4IYe0ErgvP1b3S8_qDh9ALsyNYLtdRJXaBfaXi7wGZKoiPIu3PTLExAMdYscHCJ5YaK5jx-bgkX1FrHdOjxXrgjnoo6tE-jCrRBVi9xGpK23PLOpSkj38Rm2-SpjAhpzKpZZSnKFkIWUZ9ZzRX4PFrTo3Zp7BE_VcFqxU1F5AEFyj8KpH0I6QOvtjLHLIHMSAA&state=CvSY3DNRqCWUYPA6V51nJa3cpvzxCUu_JKfMgsOInFA%3d&session_state=442a62c2-8534-4412-8368-e87a4afbd88d
```

But I see this login page again:
[image]

I didn't see any calls to fetch token in the debug logs. Ideally the framework should have handled that flow.
I have another project which is non reactive and that works without any additional code.

Tried searching online, but there are no documents on integrating azure in reactive environment.

Kindly help me fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to implement Code Grant flow. This flow needs to implement two requests in order to get the token. The first request is to get the code and the second request is to get the token with the help of code we got from the first request.

So, You have successfully completed the first request. You need to pass the code you have got in the above image you have shared as a post request to the Authentication Server to get token. Please go through Microsoft [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token) for more details.

The second request which helps you to get token looks like below

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh
```

Comment: But that has to be handled by the spring security framework. I have provided the URL for token and user info in the app's configuration.

Comment: @PraveenKamath, It is not handling by the framework that's why you are getting code. You need to write code for the second request as I have mentioned above. It will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured this out. The redirect-uri was incorrect. Changed to `https://localhost:8081/login/oauth2/code/azure` and it worked.

Thanks.